# How to upload a picture in chat?

Tags: bug, chat

While chatting I want to post a picture, but there is no upload button.

I am chatting in [Math Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=math.stackexchange.com), but there is no upload button near my send button so how should I post the picture now

Comment: @bummi there is no upload button there is the send button but there is no upload button

Comment: By design. You need 100 reputation points in order to be able to upload images.

Comment: Anyway, you can upload the image directly to imgur.com and post the URL, it would be oneboxed.